# Webkit inset shadow bug

Tags: css, webkit

This is a different bug to: [Google Chrome inset box-shadow bug on Windows, not on Mac: Better workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358560/google-chrome-inset-box-shadow-bug-on-windows-not-on-mac-better-workaround)

However, I think it is related to: [Weird box-shadow artifacts in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653212/weird-box-shadow-artifacts-in-webkit).

Applying an inset box-shadow to a text input seems to render artifacts (read: another inset shadow around the cursor) upon key press on Chrome (14.0.845.202) / OS X Lion.

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pK2PP/17/

Can anyone else replicate this – or provide a solution?

**EDIT:** Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmQRV.png

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really help you out, but I'm not seeing it in 14.0.835.202 on 10.7. Having seen some of the other box-shadow questions out there it seems like there are a lot of webkit rendering quirks that show up very, very inconsistently.

Which is too bad, as webkit powers my browsers of choice. I'll try this out on another system and see if I can duplicate it.

Comment: It seems to be very intermittent, at least for me. I have attached a screenshot to the OP.